# Create ActionResult for save throws error saying The model item passed into the dictionary is of type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Although this error is very common in the forum, but i am not able to understand how to fix it in my project. I am new to MVC framework.

View code:-

```
    @model ClassifiedProject.Models.CreateAdvertVM

  <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdvTitle) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i>(E.g. Old Samsung Galaxy Tab 2)</i></div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdvTitle)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdvTitle)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdvDescription)</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.AdvDescription)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdvDescription)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.Label("Advertisement Category")</div>
        <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCategoryId, Model.Categories, new { @class = "ddlcs" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCategoryId)
        </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
```

Controller code of Save button actionresult:-

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(TR_ADVERTISEMENT tr_advert)
        {         
               if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {                   
                        tr_advert.CreatedDate = tr_advert.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

                        if (tr_advert.IsPriceOnRequest)
                        {
                            tr_advert.CurrencyID = 0;
                            tr_advert.Price = 0;
                        }

                        db.ADVERTISEMENT.Add(tr_advert);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
```

Controller code for the form in render stage:-

```
    // GET: /Advert/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var model = new CreateAdvertVM();            
            ViewBag.Message = "Post New Advertisement.";

           ////Render Category DDL
            var cat = from s in db.CategoryDbSet
                      where s.IsActive == true
                      orderby s.CatName
                      select new { s.CatID, s.CatName };

            var catListItems = cat.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem   
                                                                        {
                                                                            Text = c.CatName,
                                                                            Value = c.CatID.ToString()
                                                                        }).ToList();

            catListItems.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "[--Select the category--]", Value = "" });
            model.Categories = catListItems;
return View(model);
```

ViewModel inherited from EF class:-

```
  [NotMapped]
    public class CreateAdvertVM : TR_ADVERTISEMENT
    {
        [DisplayName("Category")]
        [Required]
        public int? SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }    
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

EF Model:-

```
 public class TR_ADVERTISEMENT
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int AdvID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Sub Category")]         
        public int SubCatID { get; set; }    
        public int CurrencyID { get; set; }            
        [DisplayName("Price on request")]    
        public bool IsPriceOnRequest { get; set; }    
        [DisplayName("Posted Date")]
        [DisplayFormat (DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }    
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

On the save button click, i have to save the data into the tr_advertisement table using the EF model.

Please suggest the solution to this problem.

[image]

Comment: Please submit the stacktrace.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Error screenshot added..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the model type you are passing into your Create ActionMethod.

```
public ActionResult Create(TR_ADVERTISEMENT tr_advert)
```

should be

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateAdvertVM tr_advert)
```

I am assuming that if your model is not valid, you are passing it back further down in your action result (which you are not showing), such as

```
Return View(tr_advert)
```

But, you are passing the wrong model type at that point for that view.

**EDIT**

I would also update your view model so that instead of inheriting from the EF class, simply include the EF class as a property.

```
public class CreateAdvertVM
    {
        [DisplayName("Category")]
        [Required]
        public int? SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }    
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
        public TR_ADVERTISEMENT tr_advert{get;set;}
    }
```

This will make it so that your save code in the Create method can still be used with only minor modifications

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateAdvertVM model)
{         
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{                   
    model.tr_advert.CreatedDate = model.tr_advert.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

    if (model.tr_advert.IsPriceOnRequest)
    {
        model.tr_advert.CurrencyID = 0;
        model.tr_advert.Price = 0;
    }

    db.ADVERTISEMENT.Add(model.tr_advert);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Since i used [NotMapped] annotation for CreateAdvertVM class, will it still work?

Comment: Yes, a view model is simply a class that holds data for the view and typically completely independent from EF.

Comment: Now i am getting different error after making the above change.

Comment: @Karan - please see the edit.  You will not be able to directly pass a CreateAdvertVM into EF.  Somehow you have to create or extract out the actual EF class you are attempting to create.  I gave an example in my edit

Comment: I made the changes, and now upon saving the form i am getting "The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedCategoryId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'."

Comment: @Karan - that sounds like a problem with your View and how you are declaring your drop down list.

Comment: During the form render, the DDL is coming up fine.

Comment: @Karan - I think you are going to have to post your full stack trace as well as your complete action method.  Too much has been cut out to help further.

Comment: i added more sections of the code into the description. Please take a look.